# NGINX get json response after proxy_pass with lua

Tags: nginx, proxypass

In my nginx.conf file I do proxy_pass to `https://example.com/` which returns json response like this:

```
{
  data: {
    someKey: ""
  },
  status: "ok"
}
```

How can I get `someKey` from the response?